# why I can't hook my private function with fishhook

Tags: ios, objective-c

These days, I found that hook in an iOS application is hard, and found that there is a tool called "fishhook", created by facebook. I import the tool in my personal project, but it doesn't work. Am I wrong? Here are the source code:

```
#import <dlfcn.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "fishhook.h"

static void (*orig_testABC)(void);

void testABC()
{
    NSLog(@"This is main log...");
}

void my_testABC()
{
    NSLog(@"This is other log, not main log...");
}

void save_original_symbols()
{
//    void *handle = dlopen("/Users/bianyiji/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HookTest-ghlgmahvsgfbqeekbrouzdyoxgdw/Build/Intermediates/HookTest.build/Debug/HookTest.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o", RTLD_LAZY);
//    printf("%s\n", handle);
    orig_testABC = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "testABC");
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
//        save_original_symbols();
        int rebind_int = rebind_symbols((struct rebinding[1]){"testABC", my_testABC}, 1);
        printf("%d\n", rebind_int);

    }
    testABC();
    return 0;
}
```

Although I called the function "testABC()", but I use "rebind_symbols" before, why I can't get my expected result...

Comment: Headers are included using `#include` (instead of `#import`) in `C` and `C++`

Comment: it's an ios application, headers are included using #import, and they are correct included, thk...

Comment: This is objective-c not c or c++

Comment: Maybe all code has to belong to autoreleasepool?

Answer (score 2):

fishhook isn't meant to hook into private functions, because fishhook works by rebinding symbols that are present in the symbol table.

for hooking private functions you need read-write access in the executable memory pages of your running app, and this is obviously not possible for security reasons.

however, in jailbroken iOS, the kernel has a patch that allows this, so you can hook private functions with frameworks such as CydiaSubstrate or substitute. But fishhook does not support this and probably never will, also if it did would never be AppStore-friendly.

**Source**: our open-source SSL pinning library [TrustKit](https://github.com/datatheorem/TrustKit) uses fishhook and we introduced it at BlackHat 2015 [elaborating an all these topics](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-15/materials/us-15-Diquet-TrustKit-Code-Injection-On-iOS-8-For-The-Greater-Good.pdf).